# php sum variable in while loop

Tags: php, variables, while-loop, sum

I have to "sum" variable's values in while, here us my example :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $price= $row['price'] * $row['order_q'];
}
```

The code above will output if I put `echo $price;` for example:

> 19
>   15
>   20
>   13
>   10

I want something like : `sum($price)` or `array_sum($price)` to count all the results of while loop. So, that i want to count: `19+15+20+13+10 = 77`

How can I do it with php?

Thanks

Comment: why you do not use array_sum() ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply initialize a variable outside your loop for example:

```
$total_price = 0;
```

and increment this number inside your loop:

```
$total_price += $row['price'] * $row['order_q'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what i want to do ^^

Answer (score 13):

e.g.

```
$total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $price= $row['price'] * $row['order_q'];
  $total += $price;
}
echo 'total: ', $total;
```

Or - if all you want from the query is the total - you can do it "within" the sql query.

```
SELECT Sum(price*order_q) as total FROM ...
```