# counting total within a while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

In my project I am fetching data from the database using a while loop where each data is fetched by a customer id as $cid. Now all the data is calculated and finally put into a variable $cashflow. Now suppose there are 20 persons so the table will display 20 records where each data is counted for each person / customer. Now what I want to do is count the total of all 20 records and echo it seperately.

For eg.

Cust.1 : 500 (calculated from $cashflow)
Cust. 2 : 1000
Cust.3 : 800 ..... and so on.

Now these data are well echoed in my table. Now what I want is to add 500+1000+800 and echo 2300 as total separately. But I am not being able to figure out how to do it in my code. Should I take a variable in loop as a ++ counter? or something else? Please help.

Code:

```
$cash = "SELECT SUM(paid) FROM hbil WHERE cid = '".$cid."' AND method = 'cash'";
$cash_qur = mysql_query($cash) or die(mysql_error());

$cash_neg = "SELECT SUM(price) FROM hbil WHERE cid = '".$cid."' AND method = 'cash' AND price < 0";
$cash_qur_neg = mysql_query($cash_neg) or die(mysql_error());
while($cash_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($cash_qur))
{
    $cash_fet = mysql_fetch_array($cash_qur_neg);
    $cashpay = $cash_fetch['SUM(paid)']; 
    $cashneg = $cash_fet['SUM(price)']; 
    $cash_total = $cashpay-$cashneg; 
    $cashflow = number_format($cash_total,2,'.',',');   
}
```

Comment: **Do not use `mysql_*` functions please.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php sum variable in while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329535/php-sum-variable-in-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;
while (...) {
//...
$total += $cash_total;
}

echo $total;
```

Will do the trick